# Rfacebook package: "Unsuported get request" for the getPage method

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rfacebook

I am trying to extract all the posts from this year from a Facebook page using the `Rfacebook` package.

However, for the page that I need I get this error:

```
"Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token) : 
Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXX' does not exist, 
cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. 
Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
```

This is the command that I used:

```
datafb <- getPage('XXXXX', token, n = 1000, since = '2017/01/01', until = '2017/04/01', 
                  feed = TRUE)
```

I am sure the page exists, because I can access it from my Facebook account.
Also, the token is valid because it works when I try for other pages.

I really can't see what's wrong. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just because a page exists doesn't mean you can access it with `getPage`. From the `rFacebook` documentation: "This function will only return information from public pages, not users with public profiles." Does the page you're trying to access not fit that? What happens if you change `feed` to FALSE?

Comment: If the page is access restricted in any way, then you can not use an app access token to request any info about it, but you need to either use a user access token for a user that can see the page, or a page access token.